# Check if Music library is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaquery

I'm accessing the iPhone's library and doing a query on it

```
MPMediaQuery *albums = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
NSArray *albumCollections = [albums collections];
```

If music doesn't exist, `[albums collections]` obviously causes a crash.

How can I check the results of the query, and see for example if something has been selected (or length > 0) to avoid the crash?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously? It's just an `NSArray` you are getting the information from, it shouldn't crash even if it doesn't exist.

On the worst case:

```
NSArray *albumCollections = [albums collections];
```

albumCollections is `nil`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize the crash was somewhere else. If it's ok for you I'm going to remove the question as it is misleading

Comment: @Sr.Richie You should mark it as correct, as it was helpful for you. It can help someone else in the future.